# Did Google discontinue rich snippets for MusicRecording structured data?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, structured-data, music

In August 2011, Google [added rich snippet support for `MusicRecording` structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/08/new-rich-snippets-format-for-music). It looked like this:

[image: music rich snippet]

But today, I don't see any mention of it in their [current rich snippet feature guides](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/intro-structured-data).

I found [this thread on the Google webmasters forum](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/125043435/is-music-recording-structured-data-still-supported-by-google?hl=en) from a few months ago where another forum user seems to confirm its removal, however his answer is both unclear and unsourced.

Did Google discontinue this type of rich snippet, and if so, when did they do it? Did they make any sort of announcement or did they discontinue it silently?

Answer (score 2):

From your mentioned old blog says:

> You can use the [rich snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to test the markup of
> our page and see an illustration of what the search result would look
> like.

I tried [Movie](https://schema.org/Movie) schema and the [result](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=h6TmZc4TKaS_3B1fQ3BC2g) is:

> Page is eligible for rich results

But when I tried [MusicRecording](https://schema.org/MusicRecording) schema and the [result](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=S0TYSKd_5PckdiNyCfTjNQ) is:

> Page not eligible for rich results known by this test

I tried other `MusicRecording` schema examples from [schemas.org](https://schema.org/MusicRecording) and the result is same.

So I think we can't use `MusicRecording` structured data again. I can't found any official announcement from Google about that, but we can know from above result.